# How to find elements which are not visible in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, assertion

I am checking the functionalities of cypress in the Facebook in sign up page of Facebook. I am getting the error element not found.

```js
//Now checking the Create new account inputs
cy.get('[name="firstname"]').click();//i)-> Click on the firstname
cy.get('#u_5_a_BG > ._5dbc').should('not.be.visible');//ii)-> Check that error message is not displayed--> not working
cy.get('[name="lastname"]').click();//iii)-> Click on the last name to make the error message in the first name to be displayed
cy.get('#u_5_a_BG > ._5dbc').should('be.visible');//iv)-> Check that error message is diplayed--> not working
```

Could you tell me how to get the error image element because I tried using css selectors and it is not working? i have used the class of  tag but it is still not working
[image: Facebook sign-up page]

Answer (score 1):

My approach, navigate relative to the named fields.

Other class selectors are likely to be generated and will change on next release.

There's still a possibility that the structure changes (or you get it wrong to start with), so as extra insurance add a check that the element is type `<i>`.

```js
cy.get('[name="firstname"]').click()
cy.get('[name="firstname"]')
  .parent()
  .next()                               // icon is next from input's parent
  .should('not.be.visible')
  .should('have.prop', 'tagName', 'i')  // double check navigating is successful

cy.get('[name="lastname"]').click();
cy.get('[name="firstname"]')
  .parent()
  .next()       
  .should('be.visible')
```

Comment: can you tell me why my selector failed? I got it using css selector playground of cypress.

Comment: When I look at the page, I can't see `#u_5_a_BG > ._5dbc` which to me indicates they are changeable. Likely I see a different version of the page, since Facebook has worldwide servers each with a slightly different build.

Comment: Cypress playground selector is a bit "dumb", you can use it as an indicator but try to refine the selector to pick something more robust.

Comment: this is also showing error of not finding the element

Comment: So what is the error - please be more precise.

Comment: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: ``, but never found it. Queried from element: <div#u_2_a_Yy._5dbb>

Comment: this was the error message

Comment: It is not finding the sibling element using next()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242555/discussion-between-nalin-and-fody).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check that element is present in the DOM but not visible you can use `should('exist')`.

```js
 cy.get('selector').should('exist')
```

Or you can directly use the `contains()` to check that the error message is first not existent and then visible.

```js
cy.get('[name="firstname"]').click()
cy.contains('What\'s your name?').should('not.exist')
cy.get('[name="lastname"]').click()
cy.contains('What\'s your name?').should('be.visible')
```

Comment: but I want to check that it should not be visible when clicked on the input but after that it should be visible.

Comment: I want to check the exclamation mark that appears

Comment: I think a better approach would be to look for error messages rather than the element you are looking for because the classnames for these elements will change with every page refresh. But the content will not change.

Comment: but that would be a different problem. But I want to know if the error signs(exclamation marks appears) for that input field as it behaves differently then the error messages(like 'What's your name'). I want to know how I can access this <i> tag in that input as many <i> tags are generated over the whole page.